# SQLAlchemy - Adding a ForeignKeyConstraint to a many-to-many table that is based on another relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Forgive me if this has been answered elsewhere. I've been searching SO and haven't been able to translate the seemingly relevant Q&As to my scenerio.

I'm working on a fun personal project where I have 4 main schemas (barring relationships for now):

- Persona (name, bio)
- Episode (title, plot)
- Clip (url, timestamp)
- Image (url)

Restrictions (Basis of Relationships):

1. A Persona can show up in multiple episodes, as well as multiple clips and images from those episodes (but might not be in all clips/images related to an episode).
2. An Episode can contain multiple personas, clips, and images.
3. An Image/Clip can only be related to a single Episode, but can be related to multiple personas.
4. If a Persona is already assigned to episode(s), then any clip/image assigned to the persona can only be from one of those episodes or (if new) must only be capable of having one of the episodes that the persona appeared in associated to the clip/image.
5. If an Episode is already assigned persona(s), then any clip/image assigned to the episode must be related to aleast one of those personas or (if new) must only be capable of having one or more of the personas from the episode associated to the clip/image.

I've designed the database structure like so:
[image: DB Schema]

This generates the following sql:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS episodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_episodes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clips;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_clips;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_images;


CREATE TABLE episodes (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
plot TEXT,
tmdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
tvdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
imdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE personas (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
bio TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE personas_episodes (
persona_id INT NOT NULL,
episode_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (persona_id,episode_id),
FOREIGN KEY(persona_id) REFERENCES personas(id),
FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES episodes(id));

CREATE TABLE clips (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
timestamp VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
episode_id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES episodes(id));

CREATE TABLE personas_clips (
clip_id INT NOT NULL,
persona_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (clip_id,persona_id),
FOREIGN KEY(clip_id) REFERENCES clips(id),
FOREIGN KEY(persona_id) REFERENCES personas(id));

CREATE TABLE images (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
link VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
path VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
episode_id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES episodes(id));

CREATE TABLE personas_images (
persona_id INT NOT NULL,
image_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (persona_id,image_id),
FOREIGN KEY(persona_id) REFERENCES personas(id),
FOREIGN KEY(image_id) REFERENCES images(id));
```

And I've attempted to create the same schema in SQLAchemy models (keeping in mind SQLite for testing, PostgreSQL for production) like so:

```py
# db is a configured Flask-SQLAlchemy instance
from app import db
# Alias common SQLAlchemy names
Column = db.Column
relationship = db.relationship


class PkModel(Model):
    """Base model class that adds a 'primary key' column named ``id``."""
 
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 
 
def reference_col(
    tablename, nullable=False, pk_name="id", foreign_key_kwargs=None, column_kwargs=None
):
    """Column that adds primary key foreign key reference.
 
    Usage: ::
 
        category_id = reference_col('category')
        category = relationship('Category', backref='categories')
    """
    foreign_key_kwargs = foreign_key_kwargs or {}
    column_kwargs = column_kwargs or {}
 
    return Column(
        db.ForeignKey(f"{tablename}.{pk_name}", **foreign_key_kwargs),
        nullable=nullable,
        **column_kwargs,
    )

personas_episodes = db.Table(
    "personas_episodes",
    db.Column("persona_id", db.ForeignKey("personas.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("episode_id", db.ForeignKey("episodes.id"), primary_key=True),
)
 
personas_clips = db.Table(
    "personas_clips",
    db.Column("persona_id", db.ForeignKey("personas.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("clip_id", db.ForeignKey("clips.id"), primary_key=True),
)
 
personas_images = db.Table(
    "personas_images",
    db.Column("persona_id", db.ForeignKey("personas.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("image_id", db.ForeignKey("images.id"), primary_key=True),
)
 
 
class Persona(PkModel):
    """One of Roger's personas."""
 
    __tablename__ = "personas"
    name = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    bio = Column(db.Text)
    # relationships
    episodes = relationship("Episode", secondary=personas_episodes, back_populates="personas")
    clips = relationship("Clip", secondary=personas_clips, back_populates="personas")
    images = relationship("Image", secondary=personas_images, back_populates="personas")
 
    def __repr__(self):
        """Represent instance as a unique string."""
        return f"<Persona({self.name!r})>"
 
 
class Image(PkModel):
    """An image of one of Roger's personas from an episode of American Dad."""
    
    __tablename__ = "images"
    link = Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    path = Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    episode_id = reference_col("episodes")
    # relationships
    personas = relationship("Persona", secondary=personas_images, back_populates="images")
    
 
 
class Episode(PkModel):
    """An episode of American Dad."""
    
    # FIXME: We can add Clips and Images linked to Personas that are not assigned to this episode
 
    __tablename__ = "episodes"
    title = Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    plot = Column(db.Text)
    tmdb_id = Column(db.String(10))
    tvdb_id = Column(db.String(10))
    imdb_id = Column(db.String(10))
    # relationships
    personas = relationship("Persona", secondary=personas_episodes, back_populates="episodes")
    images = relationship("Image", backref="episode")
    clips = relationship("Clip", backref="episode")
 
    def __repr__(self):
        """Represent instance as a unique string."""
        return f"<Episode({self.title!r})>"
 
 
class Clip(PkModel):
    """A clip from an episode of American Dad that contains one or more of Roger's personas."""
 
    __tablename__ = "clips"
    title = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(db.String(7), nullable=True)  # 00M:00S
    link = Column(db.String(7), nullable=True)
    episode_id = reference_col("episodes")
    # relationships
    personas = relationship("Persona", secondary=personas_clips, back_populates="clips")
```

However, notice the `FIXME` comment. I'm having trouble figuring out how to constrain the many-to-many relationships on personas+images, personas+clips, and personas+episodes in a way that they all look at each other before adding a new entry to restrict the possible additions to the subset of items that meet the criteria of those other many-to-many relationships.

Can someone please provide a solution to ensure the many-to-many relationships respect the `episode_id` relationship in the parent tables?

**Edit to add pseudo model example of expected behavior**

```py
# omitting some detail fields for brevity
e1 = Episode(title="Some Episode")
e2 = Episode(title="Another Episode")
p1 = Persona(name="Raider Dave", episodes=[e1])
p2 = Persona(name="Ricky Spanish", episodes=[e2])
c1 = Clip(title="A clip", episode=e1, personas=[p2])  # should fail
i1 = Image(title="An image", episode=e2, personas=[p1]) # should fail
c2 = Clip(title="Another clip", episode=e1, personas=[p1])  # should succeed
i2 = Image(title="Another image", episode=e2, personas=[p2]) # should succeed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

- a non-nullable column `episode_id`,
- a composite foreign key referencing `personas_episode`, and
- a trigger to autofill `episode_id`.

The non-nullable column and the composite foreign key are sufficient to produce the correct constraints on a database-level as well as ensure that only proper data can be added outside of the SQLAlchemy models.

The trigger is proposed as a result of the lack of support within SQLAlchemy models to intercept `before_insert` event for `Table` referenced in `relationship.secondary`.

## Implementation

SQLite doesn't support modifying `NEW.episode_id` in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, which means we have to autofill in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. So, we allow the column to be `nullable` and add 2 more triggers to check `episode_id` constraint later.

```py
episode_id_nullable = db.engine.dialect.name == "sqlite"                # Add this

personas_clips = db.Table(
    "personas_clips",
    db.Column("persona_id", db.ForeignKey("personas.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("episode_id", db.Integer, nullable=episode_id_nullable),  # Add this
    db.Column("clip_id", db.ForeignKey("clips.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(["persona_id", "episode_id"], ["personas_episodes.persona_id", "personas_episodes.episode_id"]),  # Add this
)

personas_images = db.Table(
    "personas_images",
    db.Column("persona_id", db.ForeignKey("personas.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("episode_id", db.Integer, nullable=episode_id_nullable),  # Add this
    db.Column("image_id", db.ForeignKey("images.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(["persona_id", "episode_id"], ["personas_episodes.persona_id", "personas_episodes.episode_id"]),  # Add this
)
```

SQLite triggers:

1. Before insert, check that the `clip_id`/`image_id` references a `clip`/`image` in an `episode` where `persona` is in (based on `persona_episodes`).
2. Before update, check that the `episode_id` is not set to `NULL`.
3. After insert, autofill the `episode_id`.

```py
SQLITE_CHECK_EPISODE_ID_BEFORE_INSERT = """
CREATE TRIGGER {table_name}_check_episode_id_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON {table_name}
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NEW.episode_id IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'NOT NULL constraint failed: {table_name}.episode_id') WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM {fk_target_table_name}
        JOIN personas_episodes ON {fk_target_table_name}.episode_id = personas_episodes.episode_id
        WHERE {fk_target_table_name}.{fk_target_name} = NEW.{fk_name}
          AND personas_episodes.persona_id = NEW.persona_id
    );
  END;
"""

SQLITE_CHECK_EPISODE_ID_BEFORE_UPDATE = """
CREATE TRIGGER {table_name}_check_episode_id_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON {table_name}
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NEW.episode_id IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'NOT NULL constraint failed: {table_name}.episode_id');
  END;
"""

SQLITE_AUTOFILL_EPISODE_ID = """
CREATE TRIGGER {table_name}_autofill_episode_id AFTER INSERT ON {table_name}
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NEW.episode_id IS NULL
  BEGIN
    UPDATE {table_name}
    SET episode_id = (SELECT {fk_target_table_name}.episode_id
        FROM {fk_target_table_name}
        JOIN personas_episodes ON {fk_target_table_name}.episode_id = personas_episodes.episode_id
        WHERE {fk_target_table_name}.{fk_target_name} = NEW.{fk_name}
          AND personas_episodes.persona_id = NEW.persona_id)
    WHERE {fk_name} = NEW.{fk_name}
      AND persona_id = NEW.persona_id;
  END;
"""
```

PostgreSQL trigger:

1. Before insert, autofill the `episode_id`.

```py
POSTGRESQL_AUTOFILL_EPISODE_ID = """
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {table_name}_autofill_episode_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS ${table_name}_autofill_episode_id$
  DECLARE
    _episode_id INT;
    in_episode BOOL;
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.episode_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT episode_id INTO _episode_id FROM {fk_target_table_name} WHERE {fk_target_name} = NEW.{fk_name};
        SELECT TRUE INTO in_episode FROM personas_episodes WHERE persona_id = NEW.persona_id AND episode_id = _episode_id;
        IF in_episode IS NOT NULL THEN
            NEW.episode_id = _episode_id;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
${table_name}_autofill_episode_id$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER {table_name}_autofill_episode_id BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON {table_name}
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {table_name}_autofill_episode_id();
"""
```

Adding the triggers `after_create` the tables `personas_clips` and `personas_images`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import event, text


def after_create_trigger_autofill_episode_id(target, connection, **kw):
    fk = next(fk for fk in target.foreign_keys if "personas" not in fk.column.table.name)
    if connection.dialect.name == "sqlite":
        connection.execute(text(SQLITE_CHECK_EPISODE_ID_BEFORE_INSERT.format(table_name=target.name, fk_target_table_name=fk.column.table.name, fk_target_name=fk.column.name,fk_name=fk.parent.name)))
        connection.execute(text(SQLITE_CHECK_EPISODE_ID_BEFORE_UPDATE.format(table_name=target.name, fk_target_table_name=fk.column.table.name, fk_target_name=fk.column.name, fk_name=fk.parent.name)))
        connection.execute(text(SQLITE_AUTOFILL_EPISODE_ID.format(table_name=target.name, fk_target_table_name=fk.column.table.name, fk_target_name=fk.column.name, fk_name=fk.parent.name)))
    elif connection.dialect.name == "postgresql":
        connection.execute(text(POSTGRESQL_AUTOFILL_EPISODE_ID.format(table_name=target.name, fk_target_table_name=fk.column.table.name, fk_target_name=fk.column.name, fk_name=fk.parent.name)))


event.listen(personas_clips, "after_create", after_create_trigger_autofill_episode_id)
event.listen(personas_images, "after_create", after_create_trigger_autofill_episode_id)
```

## Test cases

Here's what I have at the moment based on the expected behaviour in the question.

```py
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

from models import *

if db.engine.dialect.name == "sqlite":
    db.session.execute("pragma foreign_keys=on")
else:
    db.session.execute("""
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS episodes CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_episodes CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clips CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_clips;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personas_images;
""")
    db.session.commit()

db.create_all()

e1 = Episode(title="Some Episode")
e2 = Episode(title="Another Episode")
db.session.add(e1)
db.session.add(e2)
db.session.commit()

p1 = Persona(name="Raider Dave", episodes=[e1])
p2 = Persona(name="Ricky Spanish", episodes=[e2])
db.session.add(p1)
db.session.add(p2)
db.session.commit()

c1 = Clip(title="A clip", episode=e1, personas=[p2])         # should fail
db.session.add(c1)
try:
    db.session.commit()
    assert False
except IntegrityError:
    db.session.rollback()
assert Clip.query.first() is None, list(db.session.execute(select(personas_clips)))

i1 = Image(link="An image", episode=e2, personas=[p1])       # should fail
db.session.add(i1)
try:
    db.session.commit()
    assert False
except IntegrityError:
    db.session.rollback()
assert Image.query.first() is None, list(db.session.execute(select(personas_images)))

c2 = Clip(title="Another clip", episode=e1, personas=[p1])   # should succeed
db.session.add(c2)
db.session.commit()
assert Clip.query.first() is not None

i2 = Image(link="Another image", episode=e2, personas=[p2])  # should succeed
db.session.add(i2)
db.session.commit()
assert Image.query.first() is not None
```

---

## Alternatives that didn't work out

SQLAlchemy doesn't appear to support `before_insert` event for `Table`, only `Model`.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.before_insert

I tried using Association Proxy, but could not support `c2.personas.remove(p1)` cleanly.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed follow-up, but I'm just digging into this now. If I were to convert the `Table`s to `Model`s and allow clips.episode_id and images.episode_id to be NULL, would that allow me to forgo the 3 triggers?

Comment: `relationship.secondary` deals with `Table` so, from what I've tried, no.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to add this logic on the DB. Would it be acceptable to manage these constraints in your code? Like this:

Event: a new image would be insterted in DB

```
# create new image with id = 1 and linked episode = 1
my_image = Image(...) 

# my personas
Persona.query.all()
[<Persona('Homer')>, <Persona('Marge')>, <Persona('Pikachu')>]

# my episodes
>>> Episode.query.all()
[<Episode('the simpson')>]

#my images
>>> Image.query.all()
[<Image 1>, <Image 2>]

# personas in first image
>>> Image.query.all()[0].personas
[<Persona('Marge')>]

# which episode?
>>> Image.query.all()[0].episode
<Episode('the simpson')>

# same as above but with next personas (Note that Pikachu is linked to the wrong episode)
>>> Image.query.all()[1].personas
[<Persona('Pikachu')>]
>>> Image.query.all()[1].episode
<Episode('the simpson')>

# before saving the Image object check its episode id, then for that episode get a list of personas that appear.
# Look for your persona id of Image inside this list to see if this persona appear in the episode

my_image.episode.id # return 1

# get a list of persona(s).id that appear in the episode linked to the image!
personas_in_episode = [ persona.id for persona in Episode.query.filter_by(id=1).first().personas ] # return list of id of Persona objects [1,2] (Homer and Marge as episode with id 1 is The Simpson)

my_image_personas = [ persona.id for persona in my_image.personas ] # return a list of id of Persona objects linked in image [3] Persona is Pikachu

>>> my_image_personas
[3]

>>> for persona_id in my_image_personas:
...     if persona_id not in personas_in_episode:
...         print(f"persona with id {persona_id} does not appear in the episode for this image") 
... 
persona with id 3 does not appear in the episode for this image
```

The same goes for clip.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I believe it is likely possible with the use of composite keys and foreignkeyconstraints. I just can't figure out where (and properly how) to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify personas_images add column episode_id then add a composite foreign key to personas_episode on episode_id/personas_id and modify the image foreign key to be a composite on image_id/episode_id.
This ensures the persona is in the episode and that the image is in the same episode.

Then do similar for clips.

Comment: Can you please provide the updated models and a test that confirms this will work?

Comment: Just following up on your answer. Have you had a chance to test this? It seems like your solution might be on the right track. I just need to see the sqlalchemy models and a simple test using them to show that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed you ER and found issue in relationship of below entities.
After below changes your schema will be completed.

```
CREATE TABLE episodes (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
plot TEXT,
tmdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
tvdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
imdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
-- Need relationship as below
);

CREATE TABLE clips (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
timestamp VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
episode_id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES episodes(id) -- No need as below
);

CREATE TABLE images (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
link VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
path VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
episode_id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(episode_id) REFERENCES episodes(id)-- No need as below
);
```

Correct relationshipe should be as below:

```
CREATE TABLE episodes (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
plot TEXT,
tmdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
tvdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
imdb_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
clips_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
clips_id INT NOT NULL ,
images_id INT NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY(clips_id) REFERENCES clips(id)
FOREIGN KEY(images_id) REFERENCES images(id)
);

CREATE TABLE clips (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
timestamp VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
episode_id INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE images (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
link VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
path VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
episode_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right... Wouldn't this cause me to have to duplicate an episode for each related clip/image? Please provide the full schema with sqlalchemy models and an example showing that this works as intended.

Comment: Why you need to make duplicate episode. single Episode will map multiple persons and multiple episodes map with single person in 'personas_episodes'. This will handle your all scenarios.

Comment: In addition, your able to add multiple episode with different combinations of Clip/Images.

Comment: You've placed `clips_id` and `images_id` fields on the `episodes` table. This will only allow a single clip and image to be added to the episode. This is definitely wrong. Plus, you've yet to share the updated models with a test demonstrating that it works like you say it does.